# What is SBS plastic

Tags: filament, plastic, sbs

I want to print a part from Thingiverse. In the description, the creater writes that he used SBS to print it. I did some research because I never heard of SBS.
I found a description on Filaments.directory that describes it as:

> Poly(styrene-butadiene-styrene) is a hard, durable rubber that is commonly used for shoe soles, tires and other products that experience high wear.

But if I search for SBS filaments to buy, there only shows ABS up. Did I misunderstood something and SBS  is the same as ABS.

Comment: It's probably just a typo, and the contributor meant ABS.

Comment: @Mick nope! It's a rather rare polymer.

Comment: A and S are right next to each other, the odds this wasn't a typo are slim considering SBS barely is a thing.

Comment: SBS is not really a rare polymer.  It's used in most shoe soles, your tires for durability increases.  It's used in Asphalt as well for the same reasons (Most of the modern Asphalt surfaces have a varying mix of 5-15% by volume of the polymer for dramatically increased durability.)

So it's not rare...save in 3D printing terms.  Only a few places seem to have made it even if it made a splash moderately recently.  I've a spool of it from Bestfilament that I've not used YET.  It's kind of hard to lay hands on for whatever reasons.

Comment: It seems that the main source of any of this is from two Russian companies.  Bestfilament (which seems to be more accessible other than IN Russia itself) and Filiamentarno (Which has sourcing concerns...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you found and according to this site, SBS is a [Styryne-Butadiene](https://www.pslc.ws/macrog/sbs.htm) polymer that only contains Styrene and Butadiene chains interlinked. This is similar to ABS, but not identical.

Some people have access to filament manufacturing machines or use pellet extruders, however, googling for ["SBS" filament](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=%22SBS%22%20filament) I was able to source at the moment two sites with information:

- [Craftbot.nl](https://www.craftbot.nl/2016/04/26/sbs-filament-english/) is a reseller who also explain why this stuff is such expensive with 40€ for 750 grams
- the [very site you had (apparently defunct, no waybackmachine grab)](https://www.filaments.directory/en/plastics/sbs), which tells us there is exactly one brand: [Filamentarno](https://filamentarno.ru/default.html) from Russia, but the link to the amazon marketplace from there shows no availability of this product at all.

Comment: Now I want some of this stuff.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Filamentarno now has got a branch in Estonia, sends plastic to EU.

Answer (score 4):

This response might be way late but no, SBS is not a typo.
[Here are the info](http://generalpolymers.net/sbs.cfm):

> **SBS (styrene-butadiene-styrene)**
>
> Poly (styrene-butadiene-styrene) or SBS, is a hard rubber that's used to modify asphalt, to make soles of shoes, tire treads, and other places where durability is important. It's a type of copolymer called a block copolymer. Its backbone chain is made up of three segments. The first is a long chain of polystyrene, the middle is a long chain of polybutadiene, and the last segment is another long section of polystyrene.
>
> Polystyrene is a tough hard plastic, and this gives SBS its durability. Polybutadiene is rubbery, and this gives SBS its rubber-like properties. In addition, the polystyrene chains tend to clump together. When one styrene group of one SBS molecule joins one clump, and the other polystyrene chain of the same SBS molecule joins another clump, the different clumps become tied together with rubbery polybutadiene chains. This gives the material the ability to retain its shape after being stretched.